# how to print the line number 5 to 10 of multiple file which does not have same extension in a directory

Tags: sed, grep, ls

i have to print line number 5 to 10 of multiple file which does not have same extension in a directory but it should avoid all the sub-directories in the same directory.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that makes no sense whatsoever. Please start again, and provide an example of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using zsh and GNU sed (for the [`-s` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) that treats each separate file as a separate stream to print):

```
zsh -c 'sed -s -n 5,10p ./*(.)'
```

Otherwise,

```
for f in ./*
do
  [ -f "$f" ] && sed -n 5,10p "$f"
done
```

<sup>(note that that one  processes symlinks to regular files in addition to regular files; add a `&& [ ! -L "$f" ]` if you want to skip them, or change `(.)` to `(-.)` in the `zsh` solution to include them there)</sup>